# SUM GROUP BY with subqueries over multiple tables

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have to solve a Problem related to MySQL queries for a project I actually develop.

If it is possible I would like to get a MySQL result over multiple tables. I tried with subqueries but without success. Here's the DB structure:

```
CREATE TABLE t_meeting
(
meeting_n               INT AUTO_INCREMENT             PRIMARY KEY,
meeting_user_n          INT                          NOT NULL,
meeting_gremium_n       INT                          NOT NULL,
meeting_gremium_f_n     VARCHAR(100)                 NOT NULL,
meeting_pay_flat        INT                          NULL,
meeting_no_pay          INT                          NULL,
meeting_pay_methode     INT                          NULL,
meeting_pay             INT                          NULL,
meeting_date            DATE                         NULL,
meeting_date_to         DATE                         NULL,
meeting_prepare         TIME                         NULL,
meeting_duration        TIME                         NULL,
meeting_allowance       DECIMAL(9, 2)                NULL,
meeting_expences        DECIMAL(9, 2)                NULL,
meeting_ahv             INT                          NULL
)

CREATE TABLE t_meeting_pay
(
meeting_pay_n            INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
meeting_pay_user_n       INT                          NOT NULL,
meeting_pay_date         DATE                         NULL,
meeting_pay_paiment_date DATE                         NULL,
meeting_pay_pay_for      INT                          NOT NULL,
meeting_pay_amount       DECIMAL(9, 2) DEFAULT '0.00' NULL,
meeting_pay_meeting_n    INT                          NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE t_user_pay
(
user_pay_n      INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
user_pay_user_n INT           NOT NULL,
user_pay_date   DATE          NULL,
user_pay_amount DECIMAL(9, 2) NOT NULL,
user_pay_year   INT(4)        NOT NULL  #<- Container the year of the meeting_date field
)

CREATE TABLE t_gremium
(
gremium_n          INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
gremium_name       VARCHAR(250)    NULL,
gremium_name_short VARCHAR(50)     NULL,
gremium_address    VARCHAR(250)    NULL,
gremium_zip        INT(5)          NULL,
gremium_city       VARCHAR(100)    NULL,
gremium_sector     INT             NULL,
gremium_branch     INT             NULL,
gremium_lvl        INT             NULL,
gremium_ask        INT DEFAULT '0' NULL,
gremium_ask_usern  INT             NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE t_pay_for
(
pay_for_n  INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
pay_for_de VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
pay_for_fr VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
pay_for_it VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
)
```

Table linking

User has Meetings that belongs to a Gremium:

t_meeting.meeting_user_n ->  t_user.user_n
t_meeting.meeting_gremium_n -> t_gremium.gremium_n

The accounting employee can insert t_meeting_pay row when a payment enters from a Gremium:

t_meeting_pay.meeting_pay_meeting_n -> t_meeting.meeting_n

All employees have meetings. For them they get allowance and money for expenses. This money goes to the society. From all this money, the employee gets max 1000$. Tis amount is per year. So if in the current year at july the 1000$ are reached, the society pays the 1000$ to the employee. If not reached, at the end of the year, the employee gets the amount payed to the society, for example 600$.

Now I would like to create an SQL Query that returns following rows:

```
User | Year | Payed allowance | Payed expenses | Payed to user
John | 2017 |          500.00 |         200.00 |        700.00
John | 2018 |          400.00 |         150.00 |          0.00
```

> Payed allowance = SUM(t_meeting_pay) WHERE t_meeting_pay_pay_for = 1 GROUP BY year (t_meeting.meeting_date)
>
> Payed expenses = SUM(t_meeting_pay) WHERE t_meeting_pay_pay_for = 2 GROUP BY year (t_meeting.meeting_date)
>
> Payed to user = SUM(t_user_pay)  GROUP BY year (t_meeting.meeting_date)

So the final result must contain 2 SUM from the same table but with different WHERE conditions grouped by years, a SUM from another table grouped by years and the user data.

The Query I created:

```
SELECT SUM(meeting_pay_amount) AS total, YEAR(meeting_date) AS year,
(
  SELECT SUM(user_pay_amount) AS payed
  FROM t_user_pay
  WHERE user_pay_year = YEAR(meeting_date)
  GROUP BY user_pay_year
) AS total_payed,
(
  SELECT SUM(meeting_pay_amount) AS payed
  FROM t_meeting_pay
  WHERE (1) AND meeting_pay_pay_for = 1
  GROUP BY YEAR(meeting_date)
) AS total_payed_a,
(
  SELECT SUM(meeting_pay_amount) AS payed
  FROM t_meeting_pay
  WHERE (1) AND meeting_pay_pay_for = 2
  GROUP BY YEAR(meeting_date)
) AS total_payed_e, user_lname
FROM t_meeting_pay
LEFT JOIN t_meeting ON t_meeting_pay.meeting_pay_meeting_n = t_meeting.meeting_n
LEFT JOIN t_user ON t_meeting.meeting_user_n = t_user.user_n
LEFT JOIN t_user_pay ON t_user.user_n = t_user_pay.user_pay_user_n
LEFT JOIN t_gremium ON t_meeting.meeting_gremium_n = t_gremium.gremium_n
LEFT JOIN t_pay_for ON t_meeting_pay.meeting_pay_pay_for = t_pay_for.pay_for_n
WHERE meeting_pay_user_n = 1
GROUP BY year
```

I hope somebody can help me. This query works with the only error that total_payed_a and total_payed_e has the same values in all rows…

Thank you in advance for your replies.

Edit:

[SQLFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12f99/1/0)

Fiddle now working but the result should be:

```
total | year | total_payed | total_payed_a | total_payed_e | user_lname
1600  | 2017 |      500.00 |        600.00 |        300.00 |        Dee
 800  | 2018 |      300.00 |       1000.00 |        500.00 |        Dee
```

Comment: can you please update this on sqlfiddle

Comment: Side note: `(1) AND meeting_pay_pay_for = '2'` there is no need for the "(1)" and also no need for the single quotes since it is a numeric field. This will yield in performance lost since the database will do implicit conversion.

Comment: Thank you Jorge, I corrected the query.

Comment: @YvesGygax can you also add the sample data for your tables using sqlfiddle which matches with your expected output

Comment: SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12f99/1/0
Yes sorry it's the first time for me on StackOverflow and SQLFiddle, this new link works now.

Comment: @YvesGygax your expected data for total_payed_a  isn't looks right because all data in table t_meeting_pay has 2017 entries

Comment: @ Khallid, meeting_pay_paiment_date and meeting_pay_date concern the payment. The  year field belongs to t_meeting.meeting_date.
That is my problem, the rows need to be grouped by YEAR(t_meeting.meeting_date) and not on t_meeting_pay date fields.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of work arround, I got a query that returns the expected result.

[New SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12f99/36)

Query:

```
    SELECT user_ma, user_lname, user_fname,
    YEAR(meeting_date) AS meeting_year,
    (
    SELECT SUM(user_pay_amount) AS payed
    FROM t_user_pay
    WHERE user_pay_year = YEAR(meeting_date)
    GROUP BY user_pay_year
    ) AS total_payed_to_user,
    (
    SELECT SUM(meeting_pay_amount)
    FROM t_meeting_pay
    LEFT JOIN t_meeting ON t_meeting_pay.meeting_pay_meeting_n = t_meeting.meeting_n
    WHERE meeting_pay_pay_for = '1' AND YEAR(meeting_date) = meeting_year
    ) AS total_payed_a,
    (
    SELECT SUM(meeting_pay_amount)
    FROM t_meeting_pay
    LEFT JOIN t_meeting ON t_meeting_pay.meeting_pay_meeting_n = t_meeting.meeting_n
    WHERE meeting_pay_pay_for = '2' AND YEAR(meeting_date) = meeting_year
    ) AS total_payed_e,
    (
    SELECT SUM(meeting_pay_amount)
    FROM t_meeting_pay
    LEFT JOIN t_meeting ON t_meeting_pay.meeting_pay_meeting_n = t_meeting.meeting_n
    WHERE  YEAR(meeting_date) = meeting_year
    ) AS total_payed
    FROM t_meeting_pay
    LEFT JOIN t_meeting ON t_meeting_pay.meeting_pay_meeting_n = t_meeting.meeting_n
    LEFT JOIN t_user ON t_meeting.meeting_user_n = t_user.user_n
    LEFT JOIN t_user_pay ON t_user.user_n = t_user_pay.user_pay_user_n
    LEFT JOIN t_gremium ON t_meeting.meeting_gremium_n = t_gremium.gremium_n
    LEFT JOIN t_pay_for ON t_meeting_pay.meeting_pay_pay_for = t_pay_for.pay_for_n
    WHERE meeting_pay_user_n = 1
    GROUP BY meeting_year
```

Can somebody tell me if it's possible to make this query more efficient?

Thank you all for your comments.

Yves